# ML : Found input variable with inconsistent numbers

Tags: machine-learning, python, numpy, jupyter

I am trying an Retail ML project, but am stuck on the Error "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [982644, 911]". I tired many thing & I know why this error occurs, but I can't figure out a solution for it. Can anybody please help me. I've been stuck on it for past 2 days.

```
Y_train = train1['Sales']
Y_val = test_val1['Sales']

X_train = train1.drop(['Sales', 'Date', 'Customers'], axis = 1).values
X_val = test_val1.drop(['Sales', 'Date', 'Customers'], axis = 1).values
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0:])

rr = Ridge(alpha=10)
rr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
Y_pred1 = rr.predict(X_val)

print('MSE',np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_pred1,Y_val)))
print('MAE',mean_absolute_error(Y_pred1,Y_val))
print('train model score',rr.score(X_train, Y_train))
print('test model score',rr.score(X_val,Y_val))
```

I am getting the error on rr.fit(X_train, Y_train). I have performed Linear Regression with the same object variables, but cant seem to perform the Regularization of the Model.

Comment: Try this `X_train = train1.drop(['Sales', 'Date', 'Customers'], axis = 1)`. Dont put the `.values` at the end.

Comment: @spectre I tried your suggestion, but am still getting the same error msg.

Comment: Why are you splitting the data manually? You can use sklearn's module `train_test_split` which might solve the problem. If that doesn't solve your problem, link a collab notebook and i'll look at it.\

Comment: @spectre The train_test_split doesn't seems to work, it throws ValueError `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (4,) + inhomogeneous part.`

I have shared a collab link : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KsnUecPnOAwKmU0sif7hu3XlqSRFhcF-?usp=sharing

Comment: @ArislanMakhmudov I have mounted my drive have attached the uploaded the csv files. The collab will work now.

Comment: @ArislanMakhmudov The problem with files was it was getting removed after runtime got restarted, you can look up the files on this link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14HxbGRXINA_yWU4L9IWq-BLsLYgfX3zA?usp=sharing
Thanks very much for your time & help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the [colab example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KsnUecPnOAwKmU0sif7hu3XlqSRFhcF-?usp=sharing). There seems to be not enough memory to train a Ridge model with your humongous dataset whose shape is (982644, 1169). The notebook crashes when attempting to execute the said line,

```py
rr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

So I tried decreasing the size of the dataset, and everything worked fine.

```py
xt = X_train.loc[:200000].copy()
yt = Y_train.loc[xt.index].copy()

xv = X_val.copy()
yv = Y_val.copy()

print(xt.shape, yt.shape)
print(xv.shape, yv.shape)

rr = Ridge(alpha=10)
rr.fit(xt, yt)

Y_pred1 = rr.predict(xv)

print('MSE:',np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_pred1,yv)))
print('MAE:',mean_absolute_error(Y_pred1,yv))
print('train model score:',rr.score(xt, yt))
print('test model score:',rr.score(xv,yv))
```

Output:

```py
(200001, 1169) (200001,)
(34565, 1169) (34565,)
MSE: 1431.9094471008812
MAE: 1058.263279968715
train model score: 0.8604548907625048
test model score: 0.8423455437913853
```

NB: be sure to load all the datasets properly, when dataset files in the mounted drive are corrupt you may get unexpected errors when trying to execute the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that solution works. I guess the dataset was large, which resulted in the wrong splitting & generated the error. Thanks very much.

Comment: I am glad to hear this helped you, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just dropping the columns like `X_train = train1.drop(['Sales', 'Date', 'Customers'], axis = 1)` will give a dataframe, when you use .values at the end then the result type will be numpy array. So please remove the .values also the reshape line won't be required. Thanks

Comment: I tried your suggestion but am still getting the same ValueError message.

Comment: I checked your notebook, In that i could see print(combi.shape) gives (351613, 12) but when you are splitting the rows using .loc you have started with the index of 982644 which is greater than the total rows (351613). If you check the output of train1.shape, test_val1.shape, test1.shape -> (351613, 1171), (0, 1171), (0, 1171)), Zero rows selected for validation and test variables. So please provide the iloc index within the range and make sure you are getting correct rows count for test and validation.
Also follow the steps in my answer as well. it will work for sure. Thanks

Comment: The output (351613, 12) was incorrect due to incomplete file upload, Sorry for that. And the output for print(combi.shape) is (1051774, 12), also the train1.shape, test_val1.shape, test1.shape gives ((982644, 12), (34565, 9), (34565, 8)).

And the iloc index starts from 982644, & I have also tried the steps in your ans as suggested, but it doesn't seems to work. Thanks for your time & help.

Comment: Welcome and Thanks..